# WebRTC Ice Servers Issue

Tags: webrtc

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Both username and credential are required when the URL scheme is "turn" or "turns".

i have getting this error her is my using ice servers:

```
var servers = 
{'iceServers': [
        {url:'turn:numb.viagenie.ca'},
        {url:'stun:stun01.sipphone.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.ekiga.net'},
        {url:'stun:stun.fwdnet.net'},
        {url:'stun:stun.ideasip.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.iptel.org'},
        {url:'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se'},
        {url:'stun:stun.schlund.de'},
        {url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url:'stun:stunserver.org'},
        {url:'stun:stun.softjoys.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.voiparound.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.voipbuster.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.voipstunt.com'},
        {url:'stun:stun.voxgratia.org'},
        {url:'stun:stun.xten.com'},
        {
            url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
            credential: 'muazkh',
            username: 'webrtc@live.com'
        },
        {
            url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
            credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
            username: '28224511:1379330808'
        },
        {
            url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
            credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
            username: '28224511:1379330808'
        }
    ]
};
```

where is my falt?What can i do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What the error message says. The first server in your list specifies no username or credentials:

```
{url:'turn:numb.viagenie.ca'},
```

You also repeat the same server further down, this time with credentials.

These also look like non-working turn servers [cut'n'pasted off the internet](https://twitter.com/HCornflower/status/829041785854898176). Free turn servers is a lie.

Also waaaaay too many servers. One or two stun and/or turn will do. Too many slows down ICE.