# WebRTC - Communication between different networks

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc, stun

I work on a project to create a WebRTC communication between an Android application and a webpage (Based on Angular 2).

I created the two applications and the communication works properly when the 2 devices are in the same network.

My problem is in the case of two networks. For this, I use a TURN server.

In my Angular application I add the RTCConfiguration like this :

```
conf: RTCConfiguration = {'iceServers': [
    { 'urls': 'stun:numb.viagenie.ca'}
]};

...

this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(this.conf);
```

And in my Android application I use this :

```
iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:numb.viagenie.ca"));
```

I also tested the Google TURN Server (`stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`).

In the logs of WebRTC internals, the only difference between the two cases is that I never receive a `IceConnectionChanged: CONNECTED` when we use the application between two different networks.

I saw many posts on the same topic but none of them helped me.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you

Comment: You're using STUN, not TURN (and there's no such thing as [free TURN servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104795/918910)). In the majority of cases, STUN should work fine, but in some situations only TURN will work.

Answer (score 0):

As jib mentioned you won't get any free TS better try installing COTURN ( opensource else try xirsys etc) as a TS in one of your server machine but before that try testing any of the network firewall behind which your users are , is symmetric. If any user is behind symmetric firewall then only TURN server will be useful else not.

Also stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 the server you mentioned is a STUN server not TURN.Also check other networking stuff like UDP flooding and no bandwidth throttling is done anywhere in any firewall.